# Enabling button from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I am trying to listen to a `FormClosed` event from another form but it is strangely not working.

Ribbon1.cs

```
public partial class Ribbon1
{
    public static Token Token;
    private LoginForm LoginForm;

    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        Token = new Token();
        LoginForm = new LoginForm();
        LoginForm.FormClosedEventListener += new LoginForm.LoginFormEvent(LoginForm_Closed);
        LoginButton.Enabled = true;
    }

    void LoginForm_Closed()
    {
        this.LoginButton.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void TestBtn_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {

        this.LoginButton.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        LoginForm.ShowDialog();
        this.LoginButton.Enabled = false;
    }
```

LoginForm.cs

```
    public delegate void LoginFormEvent();

    public event LoginFormEvent FormClosedEventListener; 

    public LoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(LoginForm_Closed);
    }

    private void LoginForm_Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        FormClosedEventListener();
    }
```

It is very strange because I cannot enable `LoginButton` from Ribbon1.cs by listening to `LoginForm_Closed` event.; However, I can close it by clicking `TestBtn` in the same Ribbon.cs. It is as if I am targetting different instance of `Ribbon1.cs` but I don't create a new instance anywhere. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "cannot disable LoginButton", but your code is " this.LoginButton.Enabled = true;" in  LoginForm_Closed()

Comment: @Hybridzz oh sorry. I mean enable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take a look at the [documentation of ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) it says:

> Opens a window and returns only when the newly opened window is closed.

That means that the second line in the `LoginButton_Click` will only be executed when the `LoginForm` is closed.

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    LoginForm.ShowDialog();
    this.LoginButton.Enabled = false;
}
```

So when the form is closed and the registered `FormClosedEventListener` event kicks in to enable the button, it will be disabled after wards by the execution of the second line

Solution:  Try the [Show](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It is non-blocking :

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    LoginForm.Show();
    this.LoginButton.Enabled = false;
}
```

**EDIT:**

> I have to use `ShowDialog()` because I want to block accessibility to other forms

Then I would disable the button first and then call `ShowDialog`. Simply switch the lines:

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    this.LoginButton.Enabled = false;
    LoginForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: This is only valid for modal dialog boxes. MSDN: Forms and dialog boxes are either modal or modeless. A modal form or dialog box must be closed or hidden before you can continue working with the rest of the application. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I have to use `ShowDialog()` because I want to block accessibility to other forms

Comment: @serendipity the simply switch the lines ;) hace a look at my edit

Comment: @MongZhu Oh wow... now I understand what this answer means. Thanks very much!

Comment: "This is only valid for modal dialog boxes" what exactly? The link you posted say : **To display a form as a modal dialog box...Call the ShowDialog method.** and **To display a form as a modeless dialog box....Call the Show method.**. This would mean that you make the form modal by using a the appropriate method. In this case: `ShowDialog`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

This code will call the event in ribbon class when login form closed and enables the button

```
 private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.LoginButton.Enabled = false;
            LoginForm.ShowDialog();            
        }

    private void Ribbon_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                LoginForm = new LoginForm();
                LoginForm.FormClosed += LoginForm_Closed;               
            }


    void LoginForm_Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
            {
                this.LoginButton.Enabled = true;
            }
```

Comment: unfortuantely, same problem. Listens to the event but button is not enabled

Comment: oh.. sorry but anyway i didn't copy that part of your code so still doesn't work..

Comment: Your problem is ShowDialog(), the code to disable is triggering after the LoginForm_Closed is triggered.

Comment: so is there no way of doing it in `ShowDialog()`? I have to use this because I want to block access to other forms